Book about a princess who became a dragon and saved her kingdom
This is a long shot but it's been 10 years and I'm still looking for this book so any help would be very appreciated.
This book is based around a kingdom, more specifically its princess. She grows up being taught never to go into the forests because they are seen as dangerous due to the fairy tale creatures that reside in them.
Years pass and she officially comes of age and needs to meet potential suitors. She meets the first one by chance. She's in this market and gets pulled into this tent to get her fortune told; things start to get weird and that's when the first suitor makes his appearance and pulls her out of there. She comes to find out that he's come as one of the few potential suitors seeking her hand in marriage but she initially doesn't like him because he's not the dashing prince she imagined.
A few other men make their appearance, one of whom catches her eye because he sings to her and is all around very romantic. Her crush on him doesn't last long when she realizes that he's not a very faithful man but at this point in the story the focus becomes less about love and more about dragons who are attacking the kingdom.
My memory gets fuzzy here so I apologize that I can't give more details. I don't remember how but she starts to become a dragon herself; you soon learn that the major villain in this story is someone who has made many people into dragons and wants to completely destroy the kingdom. You also come to find out that the initial suitor, the one she had no interest in, is a prince belonging to the enchanted forest and has been seeking to destroy this evil dragon before he can hurt anyone else.
At the end of the book, the kingdom does end up coming under attack, the princess, who has almost completely become a dragon as this point, tries her best to stop these attacks and save her family with the help of the prince. I believe they are able to save the kingdom but she gets severely injured or at least the transition to a full dragon is almost complete; it's at this point that the prince gives her his heart or half his heart or something along those lines to save her life.
I'm not sure how, but I remember it ending very happily and with both of them finally in love.
Thank you to anyone who can help, hopefully this can end a 10 year long search and I can finally read this book once again.

Just to be clear, the villain who was turning people into dragons was actually a dragon himself?
